# Evince: error while loading shared libraries: Permission denied

Tags: evince, apparmor

While opening a PDF, I get a permission denied error, while ROOT.

```
root@brix:~# evince *.pdf
evince: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: failed to map segment from shared object: Permission denied
```

This started happening after:

```
mv /usr/local /opt/local
ln -s /opt/local /usr/local
```

(I did this so I could rsync a single /opt/ folder as a backup)

note: I had a compiled libz.so.1 located in /usr/local/lib (along with libpoppler and friends), I don't think this would be an issue otherwise

Comment: ran as root, to prove it was not a permissions problem. I have numerous compiler toolchains (legacy) as well as custom software packages installed there (software development).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the way to debug a problem with apparmor at all.

You use `sudo aa-logprof` to examine the logs for problems. You will then be given an opportunity to review any problems in the logs and modify your aa profile.

It is always a good idea to first back up the origional file (back it up in /root/aa-profiles).

After reviewing the logs, it is always a good idea to then manually review the profile and make sure it makes sense.

See:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingApparmor

http://www.insanitybit.com/2012/05/29/apparmor-how-to/

http://blog.bodhizazen.com/linux/apparmor-privoxy-profile/

Comment: Didn't know of aa-logprof, wish a log in /var/log/ would have indicated apparmor.

Answer (score 0):

Its actually AppArmor to blame.

```
root@brix:~# apparmor_status
apparmor module is loaded.
14 profiles are loaded.
14 profiles are in enforce mode.
/usr/bin/evince
```

Installing (apt-get install apparmor-utils) and applying the following workaround

```
root@brix:~# aa-complain /usr/bin/evince
Setting /usr/bin/evince to complain mode.
```

Running this again

```
root@brix:/etc# apparmor_status
apparmor module is loaded.
14 profiles are loaded.
11 profiles are in enforce mode.
```

Allows you to successfully launch Evince. More information https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppArmor , including proper ways to modify the apparmor profile.

Comment: Putting a profile into complain mode does not solve the problem. Your problem is self made by using a non-standard location. If you really wish to do this, you should debug and fix your apparmor profile, not disable it.

Comment: The link you gave on serverfault is unrleated to Ubuntu, apparmor, or your problem.

Comment: It may be a self-made problem (not ubuntus fault)... but it was entirely non-obvious after careful research, as to what was causing the program to fail execution.. Many other programs (eg: self compiled Subversion), handled the library move without fail.

Comment: It is "non-obvious" I agree, still I highly advise you take the time to do a little reading on apparmor rather then disabling it.

Comment: Thank you. As a software engineer, on a development machine, I could care less about security. That being said, I respect the 'right way' and accept your answer.

I have better things to do then muck about 'permissions'... so disabling is always an option... UAC on windows? No way.

Comment: I understand but disagree with that sentiment. Imo one should code with secutity in mind.